# setStyleSheet не видит относительный путь к файлу

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
self.background.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(background.png);")
```

работает отлично, а вот в  "url(images\background.png)" уже не видит файла. По всякому пытался, и с сырой строкой, и с полным указанием пути.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил повернув слэш в другую сторону. Но почему это сработало? Везде путь указывал именно обратным слешем.

Comment: Если под Windows то разделитель в пути  либо /, либо \\